# Is there any relationship between *bearing* and *bear*?

Tags: word-meaning, etymology

Why adding `-ing` after *bear* becomes totally another word *bearing* whose meaning seems had nothing to do with a bear?

[image] + `-ing`
becomes
[image].

Was there any relationship between the two words?

Comment: There is another word "bear" that doesn't refer to the animal. Check a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear had no connection with the animal Bear. The bear becoming bearing means to support something like a weight while bearing is denoting a verbal action. An act of doing this.
Bear is a **homonym** as it is spelled the same but has two different meanings.